# Telerik MVC Grid that isn't bound to any model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

How to create a grid that hasn't bound to any particular model, and all the data gets populated on client? 
Why this doesn't work?

```
 @{ Html.Telerik()
        .Grid(new List<object>())
        .Name("MyGrid")
        .Columns(columns =>
                          {
                              columns.Template(o=> "<#= id #>").Title("Id");
                          })
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)                                     
        .Render();
  }
```

javascript:

```
var grid = $('#MyGrid').data('tGrid');

var data = new [
                    { id: 1 },
                    { id: 2},
               ];

grid.dataBind(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the columns will be bound to, you can use the approach from the [Twitter binding demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/externalservicetwitter). The grid there is bound through client-side script only.

Answer (score 1):

One of main Telerik principles is minimal rendered html. They optimize their controls to do not render without binded data, it can display placeholder. As solution, you can bind fake data and add style `"display:none;"` it view. And in script you can provide new data, call `bind()` method and remove display style.